# Recursively rename "video.mp4" to "video_old.mp4"

Tags: recursion, command-line-interface, rename, zsh

I have thousands of files in thousands of subdirectories that have the name "video.mp4" and I need to rename them to "video_old.mp4"

As I don't want to start a process that will fail, or cause problems, I am just looking for a verification of the command I am thinking is the right command.

`find . -iname "video*" -exec rename video_old.mp4 .mp4 '{}' \;`

If that's not the best way to do it, please help me write a better command.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, `find . -iname 'video*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/\.mp4/_old.mp4}' {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to `renrem` **Perl** command you can use it:

```
find . -name \*.mp4 | rename -v -n 's/(?=.mp4)/_old/'
```

---

NOTE:

I assumed your file name is: `name-file.mp4`. the rename command would match `.` just before `mp4` and then would add `_old` before it: like:
`file.mp4` ==> `file_old.mp4`
After you made sure everything looks good, then remove `-n` argument

`-n`: No action: print names of files to be renamed, but don't rename

[image: screen-shot]

---

if you have no access to `rename` perl file. you can use my `renrem` program in C++ [here is the link](https://github.com/k-five/renrem). but it does not support pipe yet

Comment: No, all the files are named exactly `video.mp4`. What I need to do is just append `_old` after the word `video` and before the `.mp4` extension.

Comment: What does the `-n` argument do?

Comment: I assume that `renrem` is a typo and you meant to say `rename`?

Comment: I do have access to `rename` so that isn't a problem. Thank you for the clarification of the `-n` argument.

Comment: I got this when I tried your command: `Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.24'; s/(?=.mp4)/_old/ }`

Comment: @AliSamii which version of **perl** do you use? check it out by `perl -v`

Comment: `This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level`

Comment: @AliSamii Okay, there is no problem, and it should work I tested right now.  So try this: `rename -n -v 's/\.mp4/_old.mp4/'`

Comment: Still getting that error: `alisamii@alisamii  /Volumes/sites/clients/tlh/public/images/videos/cities/au/hobart  find . -name \*.mp4 | rename -n -v 's/\.mp4/_old.mp4/'
Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.24'; s/\.mp4/_old.mp4/ }` That's including my prompt

Comment: Do you the right `permission` to change the name of those file? You should have it. The command that I wrote has not issue. I do it everyday since I need it a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143078/discussion-between-ali-samii-and-k-five).